# Security trimmed results for custom query on property

Tags: 2010, query, properties, security-trimming

The sites in my site collection are using a custom property to determine what "type" of site they are. E.g.

```
web.Properties["SiteCategory"] = "SomeCategory1";
```

I'm planning on creating a web part to show all the sites in my site collection that have custom property.

Here's a snippet of what I'm planning on doing:

```
SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
{
  if (web.Properties["SiteCategory"] == "SomeCategory1") {
     /* Insert code to display the current site URL on the web part */
  }
}
```

Would the result be security trimmed for the current user? Or would it just show all the sites in the site collection? What would I need to make sure it is security trimmed?

Also, performance-wise, is this a viable option? If you have some other way to do this, I'm all ears.

Comment: You want to show the sites which has this web properties as well as user has permissions on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://example/site/"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPWebCollection webCollection = web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser();

            foreach (SPWeb web in webCollection)
             {
                if (web.Properties["SiteCategory"] == "SomeCategory1")
                    {}
             }
    }
}
```

Comment: `GetSubwebsForCurrentUser()` is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks!